# Add capabilities via plugin for another plugin

Tags: wp-query, capabilities

I have a plugin I made and I need to add some capabilities for GravityView to the subscriber role in it in certain circumstances.

I was trying to use `user_has_cap` filter to get it to work, and it **does** add the caps just not at the right time, so GravityView thinks that the user does not have the right caps.

I am including a file in my plugin that is this code, (trimmed out a bit of comments etc)

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'sqms_user_has_cap_filter' );
function sqms_user_has_cap_filter( $allcaps, $caps, $args, $user ) {

    // Only do this mess if the page being viewed is a dealer landing page
    if ( ! is_singular( 'sqms_payne_dealer' ) ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    // This is meta from a dropdown of CPT that is added to user profield via CMB2
    $dealer_slug = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'sqms-product-dealer-id', true );

    if ( $dealer_slug ) {

        // This is the only (ugly ass) way I found to get the CPT ID via the page slug
        $page_path = 'sqms_payne_dealer/' . $dealer_slug;
        $dealer_page = get_page_by_path( basename( untrailingslashit( $page_path ) ), OBJECT, 'sqms_payne_dealer');

        // Make sure the page being viewed belongs to the logged in dealer
        if ( $dealer_page->ID === get_queried_object_id() ) {

            $needed_caps = array( 'gravityforms_view_entry_notes', 'gravityview_add_entry_notes', 'gravityview_view_entry_notes', 'gravityforms_edit_entry_notes' );

            foreach ( $needed_caps as $cap ) {
                $allcaps[ $cap ] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $allcaps;
}
```

Two issues:

1. Getting an error for my use of `is_singular()` here because apparently it is before the Query...
2. If I remove that check, then I get an error on `get_queried_object_id()` saying it is NULL.

I am not sure how to proceed and am looking for any input here. If it is not obvious, I am trying to **only** give the caps to the current logged in user **if** they are viewing the singular page that I have assigned to them via the user_meta.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues here:

1. `is_singular()` will return false if the function is called before the WP_Query object is set up
2. `user_has_cap` hook fires early and often - and before WP_Query is set

We know that the WP_Query object is set at the `wp` hook, so you can use that action hook to add a filter for `user_has_cap`.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'sqms_wp_action' );
function sqms_wp_action() {
  //* Since the WP_Query object is set, is_singular() should work properly
  if ( ! is_singular( 'sqms_payne_dealer' ) ) {
    return;
  }
  add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'sqms_user_has_cap_filter' );
}
function sqms_user_has_cap_filter() {
  //* No need for is_singular() check
  //* Rest of code unchanged
}
```

So, most of your code was correct. It was just executed in the wrong order.